# Form Not Responding when any other operation performed in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form (Developed in C# using VS2010) with a Progress Bar.
It's kind of stopwatch form where I fill the progress bar in say 10secs.... As Time elapses, Progress bar fills accordingly.... Means after 5secs, Progress Bar will be filled 50% and so on....

I used a for loop to perform this operation:-

```
for(int count=0;count<200;count++)
{
   progbar.performstep();
   progbar.update();
   update();
   Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

I have used Thread.Sleep of 50msec so that progress bar updates smoothly.
For 1sec, it increments in steps.

Problem is if I do anyother operation like Moving this form or even clicking on another icon on desktops makes this form "Not Responding".... But it perfoms the operation and at the end of 10 secs, It regains it's state and shows the pop up indicating 10secs are elapsed with Progress Bar Full.

Thanks for help and Sorry for using such complicated language.

Regards,
Swanand

**Update**: I solved this problem with the help of Answers below.... One common mistake I got to know is forgetting "`Applications.DoEvents()`" along with "`update()`".... If you enter this line, there are less chances of getting "hanged"!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're performing a long-running operation on the UI thread, which means that the UI "message loop" (responsible for handling events such as user input and updating the screen) doesn't get a chance to run.

You should perform the long-running operation on a different thread (whether one you create yourself or a background thread) and either use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to easily update your progress bar, or use `Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke` to marshall a delegate call back to the UI thread when you need to update the UI. (You mustn't update controls from the wrong thread.)

If your only UI interaction is filling in a progress bar, I suggest using `BackgroundWorker`.

If you're not really doing "real" work, just waiting for time to pass, you could use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of all of this, however. That will "tick" on the UI thread, but won't block the UI thread between ticks. You should only use this if you don't have a lot of work to do though - if it *really* is just updating a progress bar, not (say) processing a file etc. Note that you shouldn't rely on the timer firing exactly "on time" - you should probably set the position of the progress bar based on the observed time, rather than the observed number of ticks.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes... I am waiting time to pass.... But Using Timer is also giving same result... :(

Comment: @Swanand: Which Timer are you using, and how are you using it? A full code example would help. (For example, you shouldn't be calling Thread.Sleep within the timer tick event handler.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I am using a System Timer which generates an event after every 50msec. I am making a variable True in Timer Event and in main, I am waiting for getting it true by "while(!bTimeElapsed);" It is same as Thread.Sleep, I guess!

Comment: @Swanand: No, it's even *worse* than Thread.Sleep - it's a busy-wait, so you'll be killing your CPU while you do it. As I wrote in my answer, you should consider using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer and perform your UI change there. No waiting required.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: But What should I do till that Event Comes? Coz I want a Delay of Specific duration and have to update progress bar in between.... If I use a Form Timer then I can't use a while(1) loop for waiting.... The Form Timer event will never occur if I am busy in any task.... I want to wait... :(

Comment: You *musn't* wait. If you want to stop various buttons on the UI from being pressed (etc) then disable them - but you *mustn't* block the UI thread.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Then what should I do for those 5 secs without blocking UI?? Please give me any suggestion!

Comment: @Swanand: Absolutely nothing. Just let the UI thread respond to events - don't block it. Make sure you've disabled anything that you don't want to happen, and you're done.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: See, I have to perform a task after 5 (or 10) seconds... So, I should create an object and My main code should wait for it.... In Timer, I will update the Progress bar and then after 5sec, I will send the object! I am getting Mad... I am very sorry!

Comment: @Swanand: What do you mean by "my main code should wait for it"? If you just want to do something else after 5 seconds, then have another timer for 5 seconds, and when *that* ticks, do whatever you need to.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Finally got what you are saying.... Thanks a lot... And Sorry for irritating you with very stupid comments!

Comment: @Swanand: No problem - glad you got there in the end :)

Answer (score 11):

You are blocking the UI thread, which means it isn't processing events such as "paint". To do this properly, you should be using something like `BackgroundWorker`, and just updating the UI from the progress event.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }
}

class MyForm : Form
{
    Button btn;
    BackgroundWorker worker;
    ProgressBar bar;
    public MyForm()
    {
        Controls.Add(btn = new Button { Text = "Click me" });
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        Controls.Add(bar = new ProgressBar { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Visible = false, Minimum = 0, Maximum = 100 });

        worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        bar.Visible = false;
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Text = e.Error.Message;
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Text = "cancelled";
        }
        else
        {
            Text = e.Result == null ? "complete" : e.Result.ToString();
        }
        btn.Enabled = true;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(count);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bar.Value = 0;
        bar.Visible = true;
        btn.Enabled = false;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: One Very Silly Question.... Does function "worker.RunWorkerAsync()" provides functionality of Delay of 5secs? Coz I want to perform a task after 10 secs... According to my knowledge, it will directly jump to next line while running "worker" in background.

Comment: @Swanand you do **not** want to block the UI thread for 10 seconds; either have that delay (and subsequent code) inside the `RunWorkerAsync`, or use a `Timer` like @Jon suggested

Comment: But also, I don't want to proceed until 10 sec elapsed.... Timer is also hanging my Form :(

Comment: @Swawand - a timer doesn't hang a form; what hangs a form is blocking the UI thread (which a timer doesn't do). You are going to have to be a bit clearer about what exactly you are doing here, but **blocking** is not the answer. It might be you just have to set (for all the interesting controls) `Enabled = false` for a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You are blocking the Main UI thread. You can use a background worker to do this. You can find more details in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your code you should put this code in a function  and call this function with one thread.

```
 public static void fun1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("This is function1");
                Console.Write("\n");

            }

        }
  Thread firstthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fun1));

  firstthread.Start();
  firstthread.suspend();//whenever you want your current control to stop.
```

b'caz Thread.sleep(100) will stop the whole context not that particular you want..

Answer (score 0):

Answer suggested by Marc will help. Lon running operations can make your application crash or not responsive. I have a blog post related to the usage of the background worker class.

http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Using-Background-Worker-in-C.aspx