# Why does changing Form.Text to non-empty cause a program to display "(Not Responding)"?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have come across some behavior that I have no idea how to explain. When I repeatedly draw to a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` without being careful not to hang the thread, after several seconds the drawing output freezes and I see the dreaded **(Not Responding)** text in the title:
[image: Not Responding]

This screenshot isn't mid-draw; the image it was drawing is completely red at the end of the program, but the drawing has stopped about halfway through. **The weird thing is if I skip setting the `Form.Text` property before drawing, it doesn't freeze.** Can anybody explain why?

I was using a loop to draw the progress of some multithreaded graphical fill algorithms, but was seeing the screen output freeze. Since I was drawing and then calling `Thread.Sleep()` in a loop, I should have expected this behavior ([other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919058/form-not-responding-when-any-other-operation-performed-in-c-sharp) point out I probably should have used [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), but just using `Application.DoEvents()` stopped the freezing for me).

But what really surprised me when chopping down the code to find my bug was that when I removed the call to change `form.Text`, it doesn't freeze anymore! It isn't calling the setter that does anything either; assigning to an empty string (`form.Text = "";`) also causes it not to freeze. So, for some reason when `Text` is empty Windows doesn't care the program isn't responding, and will happily keep showing the drawing progress! **What is going on? Does Windows treat programs with empty titles differently?**

I reduced the code down to the bare minimum of what was required to see the freeze. While the program is running the form image will get filled with red by the loop. About halfway through filling it just stops, even though the loop continues running! You see that after it finishes it handles events and draws one more time to show the whole image is red, then stays around for two more seconds.

(If you run with debugging (F5) it doesn't freeze; you must run without debugging (Ctrl-F5). That made figuring all this out all that much harder!)

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Include resources System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms in VS before compiling
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(400, 20);

        Form form = new Form();
        form.Text = "some title"; // Comment this out to avoid the freeze
        form.SetBounds(30, 30, image.Width + 16, image.Height + 38);
        form.Show();
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(form.Handle);

        for (int x = 0; x < 400; ++x)
            for (int y = 0; y < 20; ++y) {
                image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                // Calling this would prevent the freeze: 
                //Application.DoEvents();
            }

        Application.DoEvents();
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your form freezes due to non-responding UI. That have nothing to form title

Comment: I understand that making the UI non-responsive will cause it to freeze. But if I leave the title blank it will not freeze. Does running the code not give you that behavior?

Comment: Nope. At least on Windows 7

Comment: Hmmm... I'm running Windows 7, .Net 4.5. I tried on a 400x400 image; (with the form.Text line commented out) it will freeze eventually, but only after a few minutes of running happily, instead of freezing after about five seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Thread.Sleep();` will block your gui thread. Your form isn't updated and you message loop (handling of mouse/paint/keyboard events) is blocked.

Calling the Application.DoEvents will handle messages from the message loop, but it is a bad practice. You allow to close the form even when you for loops aren't ready.

I think the problem is, `form.Text = "some title";` sends a message (WM_PAINT) to the window to repaint the window, but it is never handled. whichs turns out non responsive. Probably putting the `Application.DoEvents` behind the `form.Text = "some title";`, would fix that.

If you want to update your graphics on a interval, you should take a look at the Timer class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Comment: I'd believe that assigning to `form.Text` would send a paint message, but wouldn't any of the subsequent calls to `graphics.DrawImage()` send a similar message? I tried putting the call to `DoEvents()` after the assignment and it still takes about the same amount of time to freeze. Anyways, I'm less interested in fixing the freezing, and more in trying to understand why it isn't freezing within a few seconds when I comment out the assignment.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the bad practice of `Application.DoEvents()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `DoEvents()` was bad practice; it motivated me to learn more about it! [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html) points out that "even Microsoft recommends using it in lieu of hard-core threading for simple problems", and [Eric Lippert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx) says "DoEvents should be used only to fix a responsiveness problem in the most trivial cases." If this was a UI that had a button to start painting, yes, `DoEvents` could cause problems. I think it's worth the trade-off in this case though.

Comment: Don't forget to disable the close button, this could lead to stange behaviour when using DoEvents(). Is this something like a progressbar?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could disable the close button--thanks! I'll use that. In general though, the application is only for me right now, so I'm not too worried about a bad user experience if I go around closing windows! Sorry, I didn't explain the purpose very well in the question; I was working on debugging my flood-fill search extensions that I use in parsing another program's UI, and I was having trouble identifying which use of the flood-fill was buggy (some literal "corner cases"). Being able to see the pixels the search progresses over is very nice, and the UI isn't freezing now :)

Comment: I advise you to check this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp This will go much faster scanning pixels from a bitmap.

Comment: That could help others, but I actually did a perf benchmark on my code and bitmap calls were less than 1% of the total runtime. When simulating a mouse and keyboard and pausing for external applications to render, bitmap access speeds is not the bottleneck.