# PictureBox not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

This seems to be a pretty common problem, but a lot of the solutions have other context around them, so I'm looking for just a raw solution.

I have a picture box that I want to update while some stuff is happening in the background, using the picture box to indicate status.  So, amidst the code that is working on stuff, I have some lines that read like so

```
form.changeStatusBox(1);
```

Which then point back to a method that looks like this:

```
    public void changeStatusBox(int status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case 0:
                picBox.Image = project.Properties.Resources.gray;
                break;
            case 1:
                picBox.Image = project.Properties.Resources.green;
                break;
            case 2:
                picBox.Image = project.Properties.Resources.yellow;
                break;
            case 3:
                picBox.Image = project.Properties.Resources.red;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now, when I run the code, this doesn't update the picture box.  I've seen various suggestions saying you have to create a delegate, or create a new thread, or simply use picBox.Invalidate() (which I've tried unsuccessfully).  I don't really know what to  do though to make this work or what is considered correct.  I'm almost certain that the correct answer is to apply this concept ([Form Not Responding when any other operation performed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919058/form-not-responding-when-any-other-operation-performed-in-c-sharp)) to the problem, but I'm lost in it and unsure how. I'd love to see an example!  Thanks!

E: For reference, this is what's happening on the other end.  It's old code I didn't have the source to so while it's uncomplicated, it's a decompiled mess:

```
public string createHash()
{
  main form = new main();

  try
  {
    string[] strArray = Enumerable.ToArray<string>(Enumerable.Select<char, string>((IEnumerable<char>) string.Format("{0:ddMMyyhhmmssffff}", (object) SimpleNTP.GetNetworkTime()), (Func<char, string>) (c => c.ToString())));
    string[] input = new string[8];

    form.changeStatusBox(2);

    for (int index = 0; index < 8; ++index)
    {
      string str = strArray[index] + strArray[15 - index];
      input[index] = str;
    }
    this.finalhash = this.createHash(input);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(((object) ex).ToString());
    form.changeStatusBox(3);
  }
  form.changeStatusBox(1);
  return this.finalhash;
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the method from a background thread?

Comment: @Shaharyar -- There is no background thread.  I'm pretty sure there needs to be one, but I have no idea how to structure it to make it play nice with winforms.  Maybe I'm overcomplicating this?

Comment: May be the process is too fast and you can't see changing the images ? because its just a for loop with very few iterations. You should re write the code and use the debugger to find out whats actually happening.

Comment: or try putting `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` after `form.changeStatusBox(2);` to see whether the effect works.

Comment: @MitjaS. -- No dice.  The picture box doesn't change.

Comment: Try putting in the evil `Application.DoEvents();` after the calls or after the switch to __test__ if there is any other quirk; then report back! Unless `createHash` is really slow it should be way too fast to see but even if it is the UI won't have idle time to update..

Comment: Application.DoEvents(); doesn't work.

Basically, I think the right answer is to apply this concept to the problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919058/form-not-responding-when-any-other-operation-performed-in-c-sharp

Issue being, I have no idea how.  There is a lot of mystery shrouded in the answer and I have no how to take it apart and make use of it.

Comment: have you tried to add picBox.Refresh() or picBox.Update() to your switch statements?

Comment: You are using the wrong "form" reference.  It isn't the one you are looking at.  Try adding form.Show() and some odds that you'll now see the updated pbox.

Comment: @HansPassant This actually does work, but Show() creates a new window, and I'll need to cycle through about 12 sets of picture boxes.  I see why it fails though.